# How does Final Spark interact with kills?

Tags: league-of-legends

Recently Lux got buffed and received a new effect on her ultimate. Now in addition to its damage (and passive proc/refresh) it also refunds 10/30/50% of the cooldown if it kills an enemy.

How does it work exactly? For example, if I get a double kill with Final Spark will it reduce the cooldown once per Champion, or just once per cast?

Furthermore, does it reduce before or after Cooldown Reduction is taken into account?

Comment: Like mentioned in the answer below, it works once per cast, and the refunded cooldown is the percentage of the remaining cooldown. So if you have rank 3 ult with 40% cdr and you kill someone with ult, 50% of the 30 second cooldown will be refunded, giving you a 15 second cooldown

Comment: Oh, this is wonderful! Now I can get blown up from halfway across the map even more often! This is definitely not helpful for my low-sodium diet.

Comment: @MageXy It's only if she gets a kill with the ult (which only really happens often when she snowballs). It's not that reliable, although if you do get to snowball because of one guy that just doesn't know how to dodge your E that comes from across the river and doesn't build MR against a 8/0 lux yea, it's opressive. If you want to read a discussion about her ult buff, there's one on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/lux/comments/67n9dq/lux_buff_is_lit/

Comment: I was mostly just joking. I play a lot of ADC, so it does get a little frustrating when, come late game, she can snare me and ult for a free kill, but overall she's more or less fine.

Comment: @MageXy One more comment and we really should go into chat.  True, especially if you don't have a Bloodthirster / MR or a shielding support (or Lulu's ult). Heck in the past I've literally 1 shotted a kalista with the ult. But it's not that easy to 1 shot the adc, because lux can't really get in range to his the Q, and missing her R really puts her in a bad spot for the rest of the teamfight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just reduces once per cast if you kill someone with Final Spark, no matter if it 5 kills or one.

Lux have low cd (cooldown) on her R, and if you reduce the cooldown X% * kills, you will have the Final Spark all time.

Source: [Patch 7.7 notes](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-77-notes)